# What are the host credentials for Enterprise Manager 11g?

Tags: oracle, enterprise-manager

I am trying to use Database Replay in 11g Release 1 using Enterprise Manager. In the last step it asks for 'Host Credentials' to start the capture. But when I give the username and password for the host, it throws an 'Invalid username/password' error.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What OS is that host running? Did you check that the user has the correct privileges on the host?

Comment: @Mat:The host is running on Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.3. The user is oracle and it is in the oinstall group.